# Need to know where time is spent in Rails request execution

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging, benchmarking

This is the log from rails server when run in production environment:
`Completed 200 OK in 3309ms (Views: 157.9ms | Searchkick: 95.5ms | ActiveRecord: 297.1ms)`

if we add up the time taken by 3 processes (views, searchkick, active record)
it is around 550ms but total time taken by request is around 3300ms

how to know where is the remaining time spent ??

also for 3 attempts for same API request it takes different time:

`INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 3309ms (Views: 157.9ms | Searchkick: 95.5ms | ActiveRecord: 297.1ms)
INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 1579ms (Views: 110.9ms | Searchkick: 48.5ms | ActiveRecord: 212.5ms)
INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 915ms (Views: 161.9ms | Searchkick: 76.6ms | ActiveRecord: 289.7ms)`

how come so much variation in execution time for exactly the same request ??

NOTE: this is an API request. response is JSON data.

Answer (score -1):

I can't add a comment, so I am posting an answer here. I'd check the inspect of the Chrome, in the network tab, to see if there are assets taking too long to download. Also, there is a very nice gam called rack-mini-profiler that can be useful: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler

Comment: asset load time should not show in the rails log. The problem here is just the discrepancy in the numbers reported in the rails log.

Answer (score -1):

You can split the requests into two parts: backend and frontend. Backend time utilized for action call and queries can be seen from logs, increase the log levels and add benchmarks.

For front end refer to the browser console to see when response is received followed by parsing any json or any response data with rendering the final html to be displayed.

Comment: this log is `Completed 200 OK in 3309ms (Views: 157.9ms | Searchkick: 95.5ms | ActiveRecord: 297.1ms)` that of server. even if I increase log level it only tells how much time each Elasticsearch and DB query is taking. But that is not problem `Searchkick` is taking 95ms and `ActiveRecord` is taking 297ms. How to know which other process is taking time ??

Comment: Install wireshark and check every request being sent @NishantKumar